# How to use enter as a tab in datagridview

Tags: c#

I want to use enter key as a alternate of Tab key in datagridview
I have four column when I type in third column it should move to the fourth column of same row by pressing of enter, it moves to next row instead of next column. 
I am using the following code

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
    int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    if (col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        col++;
    }
    else
    {
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
    if(row == dataGridView1.RowCount)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();


    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col, row];
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Does `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");` or `SendKeys.Send("\t");` work?

Comment: No it's not work

Comment: And if you try putting `if (col <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)` ?

Comment: Same issue focus to the next row instead of next column

Comment: Code you were sended not working. it moves to next column but also moves to next row as well

Comment: Code seems to work.  What is the issue?  What event are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly.
should be false allowuser to add row.

```
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

                if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 && col < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col + 1];
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                }
                else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 && row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0];
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                }
```